# What is the difference between dyadic expansion and binary expansion?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, probability-theory

I have seen that both dyadic expansion and binary expansion have been mentioned in constructing a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables defined from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}$.

I tried to look up the definition of dyadic expansion, but couldn't find it. So I was wondering what differences and relations are between dyadic expansion and binary expansion?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Greek vs. Latin?  In mathematics we sometimes say dyadic expansion instead of binary expansion.  So you can exchange one for the other.   Also each of the words *dyadic* and *binary* has other uses, but it may not be possible to exchange them in these other uses.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks! I know neither Greek nor Latin.